# Running separate file n. times from main script

Tags: python

i'm quite new with python/programming and i've stumbled upon this "issue".
I' d like to have my main script run a separate script multiple times, get all the processes that i have open this way and the possibility to shut them off.
i need to specify some variables every time from my main code, in order for those process to run separately, each with his own "setting" that i specify from the terminal on my main file.
Can You point me to the right direction? what do i need to read/search to adress this stuff?

basic example:

my main.py file will ask for a string eg. `val = input("value: ")`. I type "Hello".

my process.py file will run in a loop, printing "hello" until i say stop.

While first process is running, i can specify another string in my main eg. val = "bye" and process.py would start again with the string "bye", whithout shutting down the one with "hello".

until i specify so, they both have to run.

and i'd also like to have a list of tot n. of process.py running, with their "specs", and the possibility to shut them of eg. with an id assigned to each one of them.

Am i doing it all wrong? there's a better way to do this? i don' t know at all.

Thanks for helping me

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do with these processes? Knowing the actual problem and not an abstraction will help us get you to the right solution.

Comment: i' m connected to a websocket and i need to start each one with their own parameters and  then automate some API calls based on the data i receive from those sockets, without running them all in my script, i'd like everyone of them to run separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spawn subprocesses running your `process.py` script with different parameters.

These subprocesses will continue running independently of the parent process, or you can monitor and kill them from your `main.py`, which could look like this.

### main.py

```py
import subprocess
import time

def spawn_process_py(arguments):
    args = [
          sys.executable,  # use the same Python this script is using
          'process.py',  # the script to run
    ] + list(arguments)
    return subprocess.Popen(args)


p1 = spawn_process_py(['hello'])
p2 = spawn_process_py(['ohai'])

time.sleep(5)  # wait for a bit
p1.terminate()  # kill process 1
time.sleep(5)  # wait for a bit
p2.terminate()  # kill process 2
```

You can naturally keep track of the subprocesses using a dict or an array instead of just keeping them in free variables like `p1` and `p2`.

### process.py

```
import sys
import time

while True:
  print('Process.py:', sys.argv[1:])
  time.sleep(.2)
```

---

Other methods are e.g. the `multiprocessing` module, which adds inter-process communication, etc, but this is arguably the most straightforward.

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast reply, i think that this is what i was looking after! i'll try.

Comment: Another little question.. is there a way to assign those arguments directly from the terminal instead of eg. asking for the input in a sort of "terminal interface"? a library or something i should look at? thanks a lot

Comment: Like the `process.py` subprocess does, you can read `sys.argv`, or preferably use the built in `argparse` module to parse command lines, if that's what you're looking for.